# Firebase Dynamic Link does not work after fresh installation (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I have application already pushed to App store and Google Play. On Android Dynamic Links are working as expecte. However, when I click on dynamic link from IOS Device, first I see preview page, then I get re-directed to app store, however after installing application dynamic link is not working at all. BUT! If I try open dynamic link again -> preview page -> "Want to Open *Application Name*" -> it opens app -> dynamic link fires up as expected. So The issue happens only on fresh start.
URL Types are correct (identifier and URL scheme is the same as my bundle ID). Associated Domain is applinks:*myproject*.page.link , so it is also fine. My Team ID is matching firebase.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNFirebaseLinks.h"
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {

  return [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {
  return [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  [FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = @"com.matcher.app";

  [Fabric.sharedSDK setDebug:YES];
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"heavenrank"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
  [RNSplashScreen show];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Pod file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'heavenrank' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for heavenrank

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.11.0'

  # [OPTIONAL PODS] - comment out pods for firebase products you won't be using.
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.11.0'
  # pod 'Firebase/Invites', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.13'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.9'

end
```

Comment: "when I click on dynamic link from IOS Device" What? From where?  Please explain more clearly.

Comment: @trojanfoe from safary/chrome

Comment: So you are not talking about linking a dynamic library, you are talking about Firebase Dynamic Links?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, as title says.

Comment: I edited the title...

Comment: Be more specific when you say "It's not working at all". What are you expecting to happen, and what happens instead? Is it not opening up your app? Is it opening up your app, but you're not getting the link information? Is it still taking you to the app install page? And where are you clicking your link from?